# Why does my guessing game produce a "mismatched types" error?

Tags: rust

I have a problem with my Rust program:

```
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let mut valuese = String::new();

    println!("Please type something to be analyse");

    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut valuese)
        .expect("Read error");

    let valuese: u32 = match valuese.trim().parse() {
        Ok(num) => num,
        Err(_) => println!("Please type e number"),
    };

    println!("Your number is {}", valuese)
}
```

i getting "mismatched type" and i don't know what's wrong

```
mismatched types

expected `u32`, found `()`
```

I think my code is pretty similar to the below code, which works fine:

```
use rand::Rng;
use std::cmp::Ordering;
use std::io;

fn main() {
    println!("Guess the number!");

    let secret_number = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(1..=100);

    loop {
        println!("Please input your guess!");

        let mut guess = String::new();

        io::stdin()
            .read_line(&mut guess)
            .expect("Failed to read line");

        let guess: u32 = match guess.trim().parse() {
            Ok(num) => num,
            Err(_) => {
                println!("Type number please");
                continue;
            },
        };

        println!("You guessed: {}", guess);
        match guess.cmp(&secret_number) {
            Ordering::Less => println!("To small!"),
            Ordering::Greater => println!("Too big!"),
            Ordering::Equal => {
                println!("You win!");
                break;
            },
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your error handling is incorrect.

The working version:

```
let guess: u32 = match guess.trim().parse() {
    Ok(num) => num,
    Err(_) => {
        println!("Type number please");
        continue;
    },
};
```

vs. your version:

```
let valuese: u32 = match valuese.trim().parse() {
    Ok(num) => num,
    Err(_) => println!("Please type e number"),
};
```

In the working version and in your version, the result of the matched arm is being assigned to `guess` and `valuese` respectively.

However, the working version's `Err` arm ends in a `continue`, which jumps back to the top of the loop. This skips initialization of `guess`, so that each arm either correctly returns an `u32`, or skips initialization.

In your version, the `Err` arm doesn't produce a `u32` and it doesn't `continue`. Instead, the result of the last statement in the arm, `println!(...)`, is assigned to `valuese`. `println!` returns nothing (technically it returns [unit](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.unit.html)), which cannot be assigned to a `u32`, hence your error.

To illustrate the problem, your code will compile and run fine if you add a simple `u32` value to the end of your `Err` arm, so that the arm yields a value that can be assigned to a `u32`:

```
let valuese: u32 = match valuese.trim().parse() {
    Ok(num) => num,
    Err(_) => {
      println!("Please type e number");
      3
    }
};
```

Obviously assigning an arbitrary value to `valuese` is probably not what you want to do when handling invalid user input. If you don't intend to `continue` and loop back to the top the way the working code does, you can use `panic!` instead of `println!` to output an error and abort the program:

```
let valuese: u32 = match valuese.trim().parse() {
    Ok(num) => num,
    Err(_) => panic!("Please type e number"),
};
```